# Chef Attribute file

Tags: ruby, json, chef-infra

I'm trying to pass attributes to my recipe at run-time of chef client.

following is my `default.rb` attribute file:

```
if node['os'] == 'windows'
  if node.attribute?('temp')
    default['param']['name'] = node['temp']['tempname']
  else node.attribute?('base')
    default['param']['name'] = node['base']['nodename']
  end
end
```

I first ran the chef-client with only the base attribute defined in the `node.json` file. My `node.json` looked like :

```
{
  "base": {
    "nodename": "John"
  }
}
```

Chef-client run was successfull and the attribute was set accordingly. i.e.

```
default['param']['name'] = "John"
```

Than I ran chef-client with both base and temp attribute defined in the node.json.
And here is my node.json file :

```
{
  "base": {
    "nodename": "John"
  },
  "temp": {
    "tempname": "Mike"
  }
}
```

Chef-client again ran successfully and the attribute was set accordingly.

```
default['param']['name'] = "Mike"
```

The problem is when I run the chef-client again and pass only `base` attribute from the node.json file(see below for the file), the code doesn't seem to enter the `else` loop. It just runs the `if' loop with old value for temp attribute(Mike).

```
{
  "base": {
    "nodename": "John-2"
  }
}
```

Any ideas to where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second time you ran `chef-client`, it saved the `node[:temp][:nodename]` attribute to the `node` object on the Chef server.

When you ran `chef-client` again, it loaded the `node`'s attributes back from the server before reaching the `attributes/default.rb` file, so `node[:temp][:nodename]` was set when it reached the conditions.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but it would probably be best to explicitly tell which attribute you want to use through another attribute (and maybe assume a default for it), such as:

`default[:name_attribute] = 'temp'`

then,

```
if node['os'] == 'windows'
  if node['name_attribute'] == 'temp'
    default['param']['name'] = node['temp']['tempname']
  else
    default['param']['name'] = node['base']['nodename']
  end
end
```